# Getting "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records" with temporary credentials in aws

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am running a react app which takes temporary credentials like access key id, secret key and session token from a java spring boot API.

The access key id looks like this `ASIAJ2EXAMPLE`.
However, it works if I give a permanent access key id which looks like AKIAJ3EXAMPLE.
But every time I get an error that the

> "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records"

I have doubts that could it be because of regions or session token. I just want somebody to point me in the right direction.
The react credentials look like:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.Credentials(check.context.entity.awsaccessKeyId, check.context.entity.awssecretKey,check.context.entity.sessionToken);
              var BucketName = 'xyz';
              var s3 = new AWS.S3({
                  apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
                  region: 'us-east-1',
                  params: {Bucket: BucketName,
                      ServerSideEncryption: "AES256"}
              });
```